# Как заставить в Open Graph НЕ добавлять заголовок и описание к ссылке?

Tags: html, vkontakte-api, facebook, twitter, meta

Если оставлять пустым

```
<meta property="og:title" content="" />
```

то подтягивается из меты description, что мне не нужно. Как я понимаю, соц.сети пытаются вытащить описание любой ценой и попробовав подставить пустышку

```
<meta property="og:title" content="&nbsp;" />
```

ничего не меняется. Как реализовать возможность репостнуть ссылку с одним лишь изображением и самой ссылкой?

Answer (score 1):

Решение оказалось не самым элегантным, но вполне рабочим. Иной невидимый спецсимвол `&#8203;`. Правда строка под описание остается, хоть и пустая.
**UPD:** Фейсбук всё равно тащит описание.